# Getting the current hour's in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB.NET that needs to get the current time.
Does anybody know of a method that will do that?

Comment: `Dim thisHour = DateTime.Now.TimeofDay.Hours` hard not to stumble on it just looking at intellisense as you type

Comment: Why my question voted down?

Comment: Not my DV but it doesnt show any research effort at all (546,000 google hits for "VB.NET current hour".)  There will surely be more to join it soon

Comment: Thanks for info Plutonix.
By the way do you have facebook

Comment: @Danny **I do not and will not do Chat, Skype, Facebook, Twitter, IMs, PMs or IRC**. This is clear on his profile :)

Comment: @Codexer I know that, i just want to have programmer friends on facebook

Comment: @Danny `I know that`, if you did than why did you ask?

Comment: @Codexer I just want to have programmer friend on facebook, but i always ask in here for any question

Comment: `i always ask in here`  you just joined today - I smell sockpuppet.  Like maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36023908.  I've never been asked about facebook here and now 2ce in 8 days

Comment: @Plutonix OK, i will not repeat this again. Thanks you all (But why my question voted down (-4))

Comment: GoTo Comment #3.  This question is not well researched and is not useful.

Comment: @Plutonix Oh OK that again, Thanks you Plutonix and Codexer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it proofs no evidence of any basic research

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I tried Plutonix's code `Dim thisHour = DateTime.Now.TimeofDay.Hours`
I found this code while typing `TimeOfDay`
`TimeOfDay.Hour` for Hour. `TimeOfDay.Minute` for Minute. `TimeOfDay.Second` for Second
And I'm very happy, thank you Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeofDay.Hours
```

Comment: That not simple, by the way i know that code after 2 day ask this question

Comment: I want that code can be apply in any Label. ex: Label1